# Wordpress Side Menu HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am using Side Menu Lite plugin for below shown in picture buttons. I am worried about this in picture showing rectangle overlying other buttons and content. I am not able to press buttons below on slider because of this side menu.

[Here is image showing above text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxR6J.jpg)

```
#buttonfloating {
line-height: 12px;
width: 300px;
position:relative;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 margin-top: 300px;
 top:0;
```

}

I am worried if there is any safer way to make this button because it is not working properly. Or what I am missing here in CSS so it doesn't take that much space.

here below is picture of this button and functions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a08Ul.png)

Comment: can you add the link of the development to inspect it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more code, a minimal reproducible example would be optimal so the community can help you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the link to inspect the elements?
You can't click on the slider arrow because of the z-index property of the menu. The div element is going above the slider (otherwise the menu would not be visibile since it would stay under the slider).
Maybe you could reduce that div size and change the position of its elements, but further investigation is a must here.